# CORS issue: Next.js API not accessible with .com domain but functioning with vercel.app domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cors, cross-domain

I'm encountering a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) problem while attempting to access a public Next.js API server from my React frontend. Here's the setup:

My Next.js API server is hosted on the domain "immybro.com".
The frontend, built with React, is hosted separately.
When I make requests from the frontend using the domain "immybro.com," I'm consistently facing the error: "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request."
Surprisingly, when I make the same requests from "immybro.vercel.app" (Vercel's deployment domain for my Next.js app), everything works perfectly without any CORS issues.
I've ensured that CORS is correctly configured on the server side to allow requests from origins like "immybro.com," but it seems the CORS policy is blocking these requests specifically when made from that domain.

Is there something I'm missing in my CORS configuration? Why would requests from "immybro.com" be blocked while those from "immybro.vercel.app" are accepted without any issues? Any insights or guidance on resolving this CORS problem would be greatly appreciated!

My nextconfig.js file

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                // matching all API routes
                source: "/api/:path*",
                headers: [
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" }, // replace this your actual origin
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept,Authorization, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

My middleware file

```
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest): Promise<NextResponse> {
  // Check if the request path starts with "/api/auth" or "/api/admin"


  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/api/auth") || request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/api/admin")) {
    if (request.method === "OPTIONS") {
      return NextResponse.json({}); // Handle preflight OPTIONS request
    }
```